# Talend studio Export to excel SQL data and group by employee then send in email

Tags: sql, sql-server, talend

I have SQL data
What I want is to extract it into excel file using Talend studio, but the system should automatically segregate the rows by employee name then send to their corresponding email.

example the row 3716 - 3723 should be created in excel and email it to markroxas@gmail.com
then row 3725 - 3727 should create a separate excel file and email to antoncruz@gmail.com

is it possible in talend?

Thanks a Lot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tMySqlInput1--->tFlowToIterate--->(iterate)-->tMySqlInput2-->tFileExcelOutput

```
                                               |                        
                                              If()
                                               |
                                           tSendMail
```

•   in tMySqlInput1, take all the distinct name and email fields (select distinct name, email from table).

•   tFlowToIterate will get the global value for name and email.

•   in tMySqlInput2, extract all the data like (select * from table where email = ‘”+((String)globalMap.get("row1.email"))+”’).

•   now take one main flow from MySqlInput to ExcelOutput and give path as 
“ur path/”+((String)globalMap.get("row1.name"))+".xlsx”.

•   take another flow with if condition (((Integer)globalMap.get("tMySqlInput_2_NB_LINE")) > 0) and join tSendMail to if condition.

Hope this help…

Comment: After Checking Use Default key in Global Variables, the job already created multiples files based on their names, now I am working on how it will send to their corresponding emails

Comment: Can you help me where I can put the code for IF condition? and Is it correct that the tMySqlInput2 connected to tsendmail by runIf?

Comment: Already finished my project without If condition, you are a genius and Talend Studio Wizard, Thank you very much!!!